# How to break from a while cycle, that is used to receive data from a socket, when the timer ends?

Tags: java, sockets, timer, while-loop, break

I have a client that receive cyclically data form a server

```
while (true) {
     System.out.println(in.readLine());
}
```

I want to set a timer of 5 sec to exit from the loop when the time is expired.
I have search a lot but I haven not found anything that can help me.

I have tried with the Timer class but I found only example to schedule the execution of a task.

Another thing I tried is to use System.currentTimeMillis() but since the in.readLine() is blocking I can not break the loop and go above with the execution.

Thank you!

Comment: read more here [java timer and socket problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673045/java-timer-and-socket-problem?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you, your links solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the socket's `setSoTimeout(int)` to timeout the reading of input stream.

where `int` is in millisecond

Comment: Thank you! It works catching the java.net.SocketTimeoutException.